# Expected number of clustered groups of cars on the road

Tags: probability, expected-value

The question is:

> Suppose there are a $N$ cars traveling from city A to B using a single lane. Each car's velocity remains constant for the duration of the trip and the velocity is sampled from some unknown distribution. A group is formed when there is a slow car in front of faster cars. Once this group is formed, the cars behind the slower car must follow behind this car. What is the expected number of groups formed?

I am particularly interested in Andre's answer using indicator variables, where $X_i = 1$ if all cars $j \in \{1, \ldots, i - 1\}$ are slower than car $i$, hence the probability of $X_i$ being the slowest is $\frac{1}{i}$. I am confused here. I agree that $1/i$ is the probability that car $i$ is the slowest since the first $i$ cars are identically distributed, but I'm questioning the validity of this probability for representing that car $i$ forms a group.

In order for car $i$ to form a group for cars 1...i, don't we require that (1) all cars before it are faster than car $i$ (which Andre accounted for) AND (2) cars 1 through i - 1 have monotonically increasing velocities? AND (3) car 1 must be faster than car i.

So I think $X_i = 1$ only if $v_i < v_1 \leq v_2 \leq v_3 \leq \ldots \leq v_{i - 1}$. The probability of this arrangement is $\frac{1}{i!}$.

There are several answers posted for this problem, and they all resulted in the same solution, a harmonic number, so it seems I'm probably the one who's wrong here. What is wrong with my thought process?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of expressing it is that $X_i=1$ if and only if car $i$ is the first car in a group.  Then by linearity of expectation, $\sum E(X_i)$ is the expected number of cars that are the first in a group, and clearly, this is the expected number of groups.

If any car ahead of car $i$ is slower than car $i$, then car $i$ will be stuck behind some slower car, but if car $i$ is slower than every car ahead of it, it will start a new group, which may consist only of car $i$ if car $i+1$ is slower than car $i$.  Therefore the expected number of groups is indeed $H_n$.

Comment: Hmm I think I brain farted. I was concerned about the case where car $i$ is the slowest of the first $i$ cars, but there is some pair of cars $j, k$ s.t. $j < k < i$ and $v_j > v_k < v_i$. I was thinking that because car $j$ would catch up to car $k$, that would mean car $k$ would form a group, but I completely forgot that once they form a group, they're going to move together and eventually reach car $i$, and that's where the "steady state" group is formed.

Comment: So I think I was actually trying to answer the question "What is the expected number of times a car has to slow down?" which is obviously a different question.